# Node.JS forcing file download in Internet Explorer

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, download

We have an IP detection script that runs on Node.JS, but when you load the page in Internet Explorer, it forces a file download of the page. How can we make it load in the browser?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that you have the wrong content type in the response. Try forcing it to "text/html"

Comment: The content type is set to application/json

Comment: probably it doesn't understand `application/json` instead try to send it as text with `text/plain` content-type and let client-side javascript handle the rest, if you are using jquery on client-side force the content-type there and don't use `.getJSON` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phoenix had it right. I had to send the data as text using `text/plain`. Doing this stopped IE from forcing a download.